# REST Api for resource associations

Tags: api, rest, api-design

Trying to model the REST interface for a system I find it hard to see what would be the best approach.

Consider having an entity of type `resource` and another entity which describes their associations: `resourceAssoc`. The associations can be of `n` types, but that isn't important.

In the case of `resource` the api would be trivial:

```
/resources 
/resource/{resource_id}
```

What would be the best approach for the `resourceAssoc` considering it's identifier is composed from: `PK(from_resource_id, to_resource_id, association_type)`?

Answer (score 3):

I hope that my answer will provide some hints since I'm not really sure to understand your question ;-)

In fact, I see the following possibilities regarding REST URLs and response content:

- **/resource/{resource_id}/associations/**

  ```
  [
    {
      "toResourceId": "resourceid1",
      "associationKind": "kind1",
      (...)
    },
    {
      "toResourceId": "resourceid2",
      "associationKind": "kind2",
      (...)
    }
    (...)
  ]
  ```
- **/resource/{resource_id}/associations/{to_resource_id}**

  ```
  [
    {
      "associationKind": "kind1",
      (...)
    },
    {
      "associationKind": "kind2",
      (...)
    }
    (...)
  ]
  ```
- **/resource/{resource_id}/associations/{to_resource_id}**

  ```
  {
    (...)
  }
  ```

The following ones introduces a new root resource path `associations`. In this case, you can manage the associations independently from the resources with root path `resources`.

- **/associations/{from_resource_id},{to_resource_id}/**

  ```
  [
    {
      "fromResourceId": "resourceid1",
      "toResourceId": "resourceid2",
      "kind": "kind1",
      (...)
    },
    (...)
  ]
  ```
- **/associations/{from_resource_id},{to_resource_id}/{kind}**

  ```
  {
    "fromResourceId": "resourceid1",
    "toResourceId": "resourceid2",
    "kind": "kind1",
    (...)
  }
  ```

Notice that you can apply several HTTP methods on these URLs to get content but also manage them (update, delete).

I think that you could also consider the option to only have resources with root path `resources` and manage the associations direclty within the payload.

Here is a sample:

```
GET /resources/<resource_id>/associations/
[
    {
        "toResourceId": "resourceId1",
        "kind": "kind"
        (...)
    },
    {
        "toResourceId": "resourceId2",
        "kind": "kind"
        (...)
    },
    (...)
]
```

To manage these associations, you could implement a method `PATCH` describing what you want to update:

```
PATCH /resources/<resource_id>/associations/
[
    { "action": "add", "toResourceId":"resourceId1","kind":"kind1" (...) },
    { "action": "delete", "toResourceId":"resourceId2","kind":"kind2" (...) },
]
```

This link could help you for this approach: http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/.

To finish, we can notice that the OData technology supports relations between elements with its feature "navigation links" but there isn't your concept of association kind.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's an objectively 'best' answer here.  There are various ways to do this that follow REST principles.  Having said that, I would suggest:

```
/{association_type}/{from_resource_id}/{to_resource_id}
```

or, if that's not clear enough based on the association types:

```
/association/{association_type}/{from_resource_id}/{to_resource_id}
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments maybe something like this is more appropriate:

```
/associations/from/{from_resource_id}/to/{to_resource_id}
```

and:

```
/associations/to/{to_resource_id}
```

That would be the most explicit.  Again, I think there is a lot of room for creativity here.  A lot of it depends on whether you expect people to be typing these in or creating the paths on their own versus pulling them from other parts of your API.

Comment: I considered this approach and I didn't liked few things: 1. It's confusing - `5/2/3` does't say much. 2. It's not representing well API calls for getting partial collections (Eg: GET all the `(to)resources` for one, disregarding the type), and the list goes on... ! I wont mind something more expressive at the cost of duplicating code.

Comment: I think this is a good start. You can add further details if you want `/association:{association_type}/from:{from_resource_id}/to:{to_resource_id}` . @razvan The only things matters that it has a unique structure, so you can easily write a router for it. Btw I would use `/associations/{assoc_id}` if that is possible.